# JQuery - Why this variable doesn't lose its value after the function was executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm new to JQuery and I'm trying to define a JQuery function with the purpose of edit a table row: a modal asks for the new values and then, the function update the table row content. But when I select the row I want to edit, the variable in which the row was stored "accumulates" all the previous rows that have been edited in the same object and when I try to update the new values to this single row, all the rows edited before receive and show the same value. Why is this happening?

I'll show you the code:

```
$("#table").on("click", ".edit", function() {
  var table = $("#table").DataTable();
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  //getting the <tr> content with Datatables API:         
  var values = $table.row(row).data();

  $("#name").val(values[0]);
  $("#surname").val(values[1]);
  $("#city").val(values[2]);
  $("#myModal .modal-footer").on("click", "#confirm", function() {
    var newValues = []
    //getting the <tr> content with Datatables API: 
    //this alert appears as many time as many rows have been changed  
    alert($table.row(row).data());
    //deleting the old data from the server...
    //getting the new values:
    newValues.push($("#name").val());
    newValues.push($("#surname").val());
    newValues.push($("#city").val());
    //adding the new date to the server...
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    //update the html table:
    table.row(row).data([newValues[0], newValues[1], newValues[2]]);
  });
});
```

As I've explained before, the variable "row" in the `.on("click")`
function "accumulates" all the rows that have been edited before.
I thought it was a scope probelm, so I've also tried to call an extern function which basically did the same things and took advantage of the `event.data` object:

`$("#confirm").on("click", {table: table, row: row}, edit);`

but with no luck. If any one can help me or even provide me some advice or documentation, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: You're adding an event handler inside another event handler, which is almost always wrong. Calling `.on()` does not remove previously-added handlers, so all those will still be called on subsequent events.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so, if my table update depends on two click events what do you suggest? Using ```.click()``` instead of ```.on()``` or is my approach totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two different and independent functions using an external variable to connect them; you can't use .on() in a nested way